# Speedfan crashing desktop

Tags: windows-7, crash, shutdown, speedfan

I have recently installed a Gigabyte P43-ES3G motherboard on my computer with a Core 2 Quad Q6600 and whenever I try to run Speedfan my computer shuts down. Has anyone else experienced similar issues with speedfan or know what could cause this? I am running Windows 7 64-bit. Thanks

Comment: I was running Win7 64-bit when my computer just went completely black, with nothing in the error logs.  Didn't know what it was until I read this post.  Did your machine also completely black out?  No shutdown screen, just a black screen?

Comment: Same here since today -- Win'7 and Speedfan binaries that used to work OK a year ago -- may be the new SSD does not play well with SMART indeed.

Answer (score 2):

Haven't had that problem before, but found a couple of command line switches you can try from this article:  http://www.almico.com/sfarticle.php?id=3

**The /NOSMARTSCAN switch**

> SpeedFan uses standard calls to the OS
>   to access S.M.A.R.T. info.
>   Unfortunately, some drivers do not
>   work fine and cause the whole system
>   to crash when queried the standard
>   way. Such drivers included some from
>   Silicon Image and some others from
>   nVidia (for nForce 4). You will see
>   that every S.M.A.R.T. enabled tool
>   will crash with such drivers. This
>   switch will prevent SpeedFan from
>   accessing S.M.A.R.T.. You will not see
>   any info about your IDE or SATA hard
>   disks.

**The /NOSUPERIO switch**

> The SuperIO chip contains several
>   functionalities. From the keyboard
>   interface, to floppy, serial and
>   parallel ports, power management and
>   so on. Some SuperIO chips also contain
>   hardware monitoring capabilities
>   and/or fan control support. This is
>   the reason why SpeedFan tries to
>   automatically identify them. This
>   works most of the time, but it looks
>   like that some manufacturers are using
>   custom devices and configurations that
>   collide with this detection process.
>   Such manufacturers include DELL (but
>   not all DELL products). If SpeedFan
>   hangs or causes your system to crash,
>   this switch will be a good candidate
>   for a fix.

Comment: I've got a Gigabyte G41M machine with the same issue. These flags don't resolve the problem :/

Comment: Yup, the /NOSMARTSCAN switch worked for me on my PENGATRON Corp. G60VX 1.0